# Kendo AngularJS Date picker - how to set ng-model from timestamp to formatted date?He

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, kendo-ui, datepicker

A have the following date time picker based on the documentation
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/angular
:

```
<input kendo-date-picker
                     k-options="monthSelectorOptions"
                     ng-model="milestone.estimate"
                     k-ng-model="dateObject" />
```

With following options:

```
  // SET OPTIONS FOR DATE TIME PICKER
  $scope.monthSelectorOptions = {
    format: "dd.MM.yyyy",
    change: $scope.onDateChange
  };
```

I would like to ask how can i do automatical date formatting from timestamp which is represented by:

```
ng-model="milestone.estimate"
```

And after the selection date from picker update value in scope to timestamp but with formatted date displayed in the date picker.

Is it possible and how can i do it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the angularjs date filter? It's right there in the example you showed:

```
<div class="demo-section k-content"ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="box-col">
        <h4>Select date:</h4>
        <input kendo-date-picker
         ng-model="dateString"
         k-ng-model="dateObject" />
```

Then further down...

```
dateObject: {{ dateObject | date:"EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy" }}
```

Renders the date very similar to how you wanted. Read more here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: But i cannot use filter in this case in the template: ng-model="{{milestone.actual | date:'medium'}}" and i dont know how i can access to the dateObject from Controller.

Comment: Could You please add some example, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseFormats` kendo property, to let kendo knows in which format the input is

```
parseFormats: ["dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss"] // e.g. 11/03/2015T18:05:00
```

In your configurations:

```
// SET OPTIONS FOR DATE TIME PICKER
 $scope.monthSelectorOptions = {
    format: "dd.MM.yyyy",
    parseFormats: ["dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss"], // e.g. 11/03/2015T18:05:00
    change: $scope.onDateChange
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

To format the date in angular code use, you call the formatDate function by using ng-change on the input and passing yr ng-model with it, since the ng-model is also attached to the kendo calendar the ng-change format the ng-model

```
    function formatDate(anyDate) {
        return $filter('date')(anyDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    }

$scope.formatDate = function(anyDate){
       return $filter('date')(anyDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
}
```

and inject this into yr controller $filter